# Implement an Interface that extends multiple Interfaces with Generic Parameters - JAVA

Tags: java

I'm running into a problem on how to implement an interface that extends two other interfaces with generics.

The error I got is

> Type parameter 'E' is not within its bound; should implement 'java.lang.Comparable< E >

Bottom is my code:

```
public interface MyUnorderedList<E extends Comparable<E>> extends Iterable<E>
{ // My Code}

public class MyLinkedList<E> implements MyUnorderedList<E>
{// My Code}
```

Comment: How about `public class MyLinkedLIst<E extends Comparable<E>> implements MyUnorderedList<E> {}`?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.